# ElasticSearch 7.6 failed to start after clean install

Tags: java, elasticsearch, nginx

I have done a clean install of ElasticSearch port 9200 localhost everything default. When starting the following error below is displayed and Failed. I'm running nginx this should not matter and openjdk version "1.8.0_332"

```
Starting elasticsearch (via systemctl):  Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
                                                           [FAILED]


:journalctl -xe
-- 
-- Unit elasticsearch.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Aug 31 10:53:41 ip-172-26-7-39.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.
Aug 31 10:53:41 ip-172-26-7-39.ec2.internal systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service failed.
Aug 31 10:53:41 ip-172-26-7-39.ec2.internal sudo[31438]: pam_unix(sudo-i:session): session closed for user root
Aug 31 10:53:42 ip-172-26-7-39.ec2.internal log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch[31563]: cat: /proc/31469/stat: No such file or directory
Aug 31 10:53:42 ip-172-26-7-39.ec2.internal log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch[31563]: [log4j-hotpatch] Process 31469 no longer a java process, skipping.
Aug 31 10:53:42 ip-172-26-7-39.ec2.internal root[31640]: Process 31469 no longer a java process, skipping.
Aug 31 10:53:52 ip-172-26-7-39.ec2.internal systemd[1]: log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 31 10:53:52 ip-172-26-7-39.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Run the CVE-2021-44228 hotfix script.
-- Subject: Unit log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch.service has finished shutting down.
Aug 31 10:53:52 ip-172-26-7-39.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Started Run the CVE-2021-44228 hotfix script.
-- Subject: Unit log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Aug 31 10:53:52 ip-172-26-7-39.ec2.internal log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch[31649]: [log4j-hotpatch] Starting up now...
Aug 31 10:53:52 ip-172-26-7-39.ec2.internal root[31650]: Starting up now...
Aug 31 10:53:52 ip-172-26-7-39.ec2.internal log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch[31649]: [log4j-hotpatch] No JVMs found, exiting gracefully
Aug 31 10:53:52 ip-172-26-7-39.ec2.internal root[31656]: No JVMs found, exiting gracefully
```

Comment: The last line states `No JVMs found`?!

Comment: @Val java is installed 1.8.0 ... `echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jre`

Comment: 7.6 is [EOL](https://www.elastic.co/support/eol), please use a more up to date version